# Link to bookmark from shape does not work with Word Web App (2010)?

Tags: 2010, word, office-web-apps

I am trying to create a clickable shape that links to a bookmark in the same Word document. This works fine when viewing the document in Microsoft Word, but does not work when viewing in SharePoint 2010 (Word Web App).

Is this a known issue, or am I doing something wrong? Is there a workaround or resolution?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it does not support it.

> Rob Rolnick asked on November 16, 2010
>
> Microsoft
>
> The Word Web App does not currently support navigating to bookmarks.

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/webapps-word/does-office-web-apps-support-navigation-to/d671f0a8-41a5-447a-aef2-1294e1ecfbcb